# Troubleshooting my c++ programs

Tags: c++

I've got these 2 programs for the current chapter in my C++ class that I cant seem to get to work and I dont understand why.

The first project requests

> "Create a program that displays the appropriate shipping charge based on the zip code entered by the user. To be valid, the zip code must contain exactly five digits and the first three digits must be either “605” or “606”. The shipping charge for “605” zip codes is $25. The shipping charge for “606” zip codes is $30. Display an appropriate error message if the zip code entered is invalid. Use the sentinel value “X” to end the program."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string zipCode = "";
string zip = "";

int main() {
    cout << "ENTER AN X TO STOP ZIP CODE DATA ENTRY." << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter Zip Code: ";
getline(cin, zipCode);
while (zipCode != "x")
{
    if (zipCode.length() == 5)
    {
        if (zipCode.find("605", 0))
                        {
                        cout << "Shipping charge is $25" << endl;
                        }
                    else if (zipCode.find("606", 0))
                        {
                        cout << "Shipping charge is $30" << endl;
                        }
                    else
                        cout << "Invalid Zip Code.";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Zip code must contain exactly 5 digits." << endl;
    }
cout << "Enter Zip Code: ";
getline(cin, zipCode);
}

cout << endl << "End of Program.";

return 0;
}
```

I tried a similar structure for the second program and cant get it to work properly either.

> Create a program that displays the color of the item whose number is entered by the user. All item numbers contain exactly seven characters. All items are available in four colors: blue, green, red, and white. The fourth character in the item number indicates the item number, as follows: a B or b indicates Blue, a G or g indicates Green, a R or r indicates Red, and a W or w indicates White. If the item number is not exactly seven characters display the appropriate error message. If the fourth character is not one of the valid color characters, display the appropriate error message. Use the sentinel value “X” to end the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string itemCode = "";

int main() {
cout << "ENTER AN X TO STOP ITEM NUMBER DATA ENTRY." << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter Item Number: ";
getline(cin, itemCode);
while (itemCode != "x")
{
    if (itemCode.length() == 7)
    {
        if (itemCode.find("B", 3) == "B")
                        {
                        cout << "Color is blue." << endl;
                        }
                    else if (itemCode.find("G", 3) == "G")
                        {
                        cout << "Color is green." << endl;
                        }
                    else if (itemCode.find("R", 3) == "R")
                        {
                        cout << "Color is Red." << endl;
                        }
                    else if (itemCode.find("W", 3) == "W")
                        {
                        cout << "Color is White." << endl;
                        }
                    else

                        cout << "Invalid color code found in item number.";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Item number must contain exactly 7 characters." << endl;
    }
cout << "Enter Item Number: ";
getline(cin, itemCode);
}

cout << endl << "End of Program.";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally you want to ask one question per question.  You should also work on properly indenting your code and adding the input you're using, the expected output, the actual output, and what you think is wrong.  Using a debugger to step through your programs would probably help you track this down and is a valuable skill to learn.

Comment: The indentation is just because I was copying it from one program to another, and it just kinda went haywire. But as far as there being two questions is just cause the 2 programs basically are doing the same thing where its suppose to be finding something in the string and displaying a correct output in relation to whats in the string.

My problem is that in the first program it just always says 25 regardless of what zip code it is.
The second program just always displays the blue response. Both of them are not properly searching the string and I cant figure out why.

Comment: The sentinel value to end the program works, the testing of the length works, its just the part that searches the string that just doesnt display the proper result

Comment: Pay careful attention to what [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns for success and failure.

Comment: success and failure? as long as its not a sentinel value and has correct length, it just returns the first result no matter what the value is

Comment: No, it does not return a simple success and failure.  I provided a link to the documentation, read it.  The way you are using it the strings that start with the correct value fail and the ones that don't contain it at all pass.

Answer (score 0):

From glancing at your code, two obvious problems come to mind that's likely the source of your issues:

- You're not checking if `getline` successfully grabbed the input.
- Your usage of `string::find`'s return value is wrong. You need to check for `std::npos` to see if there's a match or not. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find) if you need more details.

For your first problem, you want something like:

```
while (getline(cin, zipCode) && zipCode != "x")
// ...
```

And removing the other `getline`s.

For the second, your usage should look something like:

```
if (zipCode.find("605", 0) != string::npos)
// ...
```

Your current `if (zipCode.find("605", 0))` does not work because anything other than `0` or `false` is considered truthy. `std::string::npos` is typically defined as `-1` which means the expression is true if the `zipCode` isn't found -- the opposite of your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt quite understand how the find function worked in what it returned. 

So now I got the first program to work, my only question now is that in the second program, searching for the correct letter in the itemCode is case sensitive, how can I get it to search for the upper and lowercase version in the correct subscript?

Comment: Got second program to work with 

std::transform(itemCode.begin(), itemCode.end(), itemCode.begin(), ::tolower);

Comment: Remember you can upvote and/or accept my reply if it's helpful.